# Get and change value of CSS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css

I have a simple page as:

```html
<aura:component>
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="column1">
            some stuff
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            some other stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

```css
.tab {
    display: flex;
}

.column1 {
    width: 75%;
}

.column2 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

And I wan't to use this script:

```js
var h = document.getElementByClass("column1").style.height;
document.getElementByClass("column2").style.maxHeight = h;
```

But I can't use `document` in an `aura:component`, How can I translate this to fit with the `aura:componente` norme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Aura we have [Lightning Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) which prevents accessing you the dom like that.
Give an `aura:id` to your div.

```
<div class="tab" aura:id="columnDiv">
    <div class="column1">
        some stuff
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        some other stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Then from controller you can access its element via:

```
component.find('columnDiv').getElement().style.maxHeight = h;
```

But I would suggest to check for null first before checking for `.style`